# How to create a VAR model with robust estimators of the covariance variance in $R$?

Tags: vector-autoregression

I have a problem with autocorrelation in my VAR model, even when I raise a lag order. How can I introduce robust estimators of variance and covariance matrices into the model? How do such estimators affect the model (how will the interpretation or properties change)?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: This should be deleted given a later question.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is redundant given a later question. How to do stuff in R is not central here either.